# Chrome Extension focus on one tab ID

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm building my first extension which searches a site, Craigslist for example, page by page (with about a 5 second delay between moving to the next page) looking for certain titles/text, etc.

When I turn my extension on and the tab is at the right URL, it starts to go page to page as expected. The issue is when I open a new tab, if I'm looking at the new tab at the time the next page is loading for my extension (on a different tab), it loads the next page in whatever tab I'm focused on at that moment.

I want the extension to grab the tab ID of the tab I'm viewing at the time I hit enable in my extension, then only update that tab going forward if its still open. Then maybe if that tab gets closed, the extension switches to disable automatically.

I use:

```
var myNewUrl = "https://example-site-url.com/?page=" + slice; //slice is the page number
chrome.tabs.update ({url: myNewUrl});
```

to update the URL, which works fine.

Here is my enable option/button I use in background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(end => {
    myButton = () => {
        enabled = !enabled;
        myButton.textContent = enabled ? 'Disable' : 'Enable';
        chrome.storage.local.set({enabled:enabled});
    };
});
```

The enable/disable works as expected too.

When I set it to enabled, can I grab the tab ID there in that function? Then call it in the `chrome.tabs.update ({url: myNewUrl});`?

I have the following in my manifest file which I believe is necessary:

```
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
```

I looked through the Chrome Tabs documentation (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/) and I primarily don't understand it. I tried using the **Get the current tab** code to return tab unsuccessfully. All my attempts pretty much crash the extension and it does not move forward at all.

---

My entire background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(slice => {
    var myNewUrl = "https://example-site.com/?page=" + slice;
    chrome.tabs.update ({url: myNewUrl});
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(end => {
    myButton = () => {
        enabled = !enabled;
        myButton.textContent = enabled ? 'Disable' : 'Enable';
        chrome.storage.local.set({enabled:enabled});
    };
});
```

Almost all of the rest of my code is in the content-script.js, which sounds like it is not proper from what I'm reading elsewhere.

There, in the content-script, most of my code is under this, which is controlled by the enable/disable button:

```
chrome.storage.local.get("enabled", (data) => {
  if (data.enabled) {
```

Comment: Show more of the listener/context where your first code block runs please.

Comment: Sure. I added the My background.js section at the bottom of my original post. There is not much in my background .js file, and most is in the content script, which I do not think is the way to do it.

Comment: Use onMessage listener's second parameter: (slice, sender) => { .... chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {url: ......

Comment: Does sender need to be defined somewhere? I get a: Service worker registration failed for "service_worker": "background.js". I was seeing that previously while trying to get this to work as well.

Comment: My comment says and shows that sender is the second parameter.